# Unexpected character in input: '\' while installing Laravel 4 in a dreamhost account

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dreamhost

I've been trying for the last hours to install Laravel 4 on my dreamhost account but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/user/test/artisan on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/user/test/artisan on line 46
```

When I run

```
/usr/local/bin/php-5.4 -d memory_limit=256M composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel test
```

I've read that it may be because I use the wrong php version, but I've run the command above with

- /usr/local/bin/php-5.4
- /usr/local/bin/php-5.3
- /usr/local/php53/bin/php
- /usr/local/php54/bin/php

With the same result. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.idlehamster.com/blog/installing-laravel-4-on-dreamhost

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, exact same error.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by the answer from Sheikh Heera, the composer.phar must be run with PHP 5.3 or higher.

What has not been mentioned yet is that `composer.json` contains several references to PHP binary. When installing Laravel in an environment where PHP defaults to a version lower than 5.3  (e.g. WebFaction servers), all references to "php" within file `composer.json` must be changed to point to a newer version of PHP.

For example:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
  "php artisan optimize"
],
```

... must be changed to (something like):

```
"post-install-cmd": [
  "php54 artisan optimize"
],
```

Comment: 7 months later, this saved my bacon. This isn't mentioned anywhere! Just 'rawr update to 5.3+!!'. Fantastic catch!

Comment: This was exactly my problem, using shared hosting and they support PHP 5.3+ but their default was 5.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `artisan` on line `46` there is

```
$artisan = Illuminate\Console\Application::start($app);
```

And according to the arror message `Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\'` the `PHP` parser didn't recognize the `\` which is being used for `namespace` since`PHP 5.3.0` so it's clear that your `PHP` version is incorrect. Try to upgrade it. Check you version using

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php -v
```

Comment: Then maybe something else is wrong but if `5.3.0 or higher` is installed then it' not about `namespace`. Are you sure about your version ?

Answer (score 0):

I was guessing this was a PHP version issue and was right. thanks for the other answers guys!

Here is the specific answer if you have hosting from 1and1 / 1&1
create a .htaccess file in the root of your domain with this code in it

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php
```

Note: the "php6" maps to php version 5.4
also note, if there is already a .htaccess file, which there probably is, simply create a line at the beginning and insert this line of code. for example, my .htaccess file for a laravel 5 root domain looks like 
(thanks to help from http://laravel.io/forum/03-21-2014-laravel-production-deployment-on-1and1)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note the / added to the RewriteRule ^ ... line as well as the php6 part

should be all good, check out their help link here

https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/manually-set-the-version-of-php-using-an-htaccess-file-a614325.html