# Laravel php artisan migrate not working on server with ssh from console

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ionos

I try to install my website on a server. I connected via ssh to the server to run 'php artisan migrate', but it didnt work and only show me the following error:

(uiserver):u108900605:~/portfolio$ php artisan migrate
Content-type: text/html

**Warning**:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in **/homepages/10/d916348811/htdocs/portfolio/artisan** on line **33**

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in **/homepages/10/d916348811/htdocs/portfolio/artisan** on line **33**

How can i solve this?

Comment: can you do `php artisan key:generate --show`?

Comment: Searching for your error turns up many answers, all with the same answer: your PHP version does not support namespaces: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14975613/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17287934/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14975613/6089612, ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: running artisan gives me "Unexpected character in input" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975613/laravel-running-artisan-gives-me-unexpected-character-in-input-error)

Answer (score 1):

i think this is php version problem or server configuration problem. check your environment is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).